# Tally ERP: Bank Statement option disabled

Tags: tally

I created a new ledger account for a Bank in tally. Now I want to import Bank Statement. But the option in the reconciliation menu is disabled. How to enable it?

Tried changing configure options for the bank. Doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the [auto-reconciliation option is disabled](https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/Tally.ERP9/Banking/import_bank_stmt_in_bank_recon.htm).

[image: Bank Account Configurqation]